# What permissions are necessary to view remote Performance Counter data?

Tags: permissions, remote, performance-monitor

In Win2k3, I open Performance Monitor, and click "Add" to add a new counter. Instead of the local machine name, I type `\\REMOTENAME` and I get a message that says:

> Unable to connect to machine

On the target machine, I've added the original machine's account and my domain account to the "Performance Monitor Users" group, but alas, I still get the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured out the problem - this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922775) mentions that the Remote Registry service needs to be started on the remote machine for things to work properly. Starting it fixed my issue.